# How can I group correctly in mongo by two fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having trouble to group a document. I have the following fields:

```
{
    field: "someId1",
    data: [{"foo":"bar"}]
},
{
    field: "someId2",
    associatedField: "someId1" //same as field value above
    data: [{"foo":"bar1"},{"foo":"bar2"}]
},
{
    field: "someId3",
    data:[{"foo":"bar3"}]
}
```

What I want after grouping these entries is something like this:

```
{
    field: "someId1",
    associatedField: "someId2",
    data:[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"bar1"},{"foo":"bar2"}]
},
{
    field: "someId3",
    data:[{"foo":"bar3"}]
}
```

There is another limitation that I am having, not all entries have an associated field (like the 3rd entry), so whenever I try to group by {field, associatedField} some of them remain ungrouped.

To be more clear, because the 2nd document is associated with the 1st, I would like them to be grouped and have only 1 data array associated, containing all values from 1 and 2.

Is there any solution for solving this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you write with words the field or the expression(operations on fields) , you what to group by? {field, associatedField}  what it means? Why the first 2 ended in the same group, and why associatedField became 2?

Comment: @Takis_ I have modified the description, I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

You could get what you want with a $lookup aggregation and a $concatArrays.

Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nhJhbvxtwCB)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "collection",
            "localField": "associatedField",
            "foreignField": "field",
            "as": "temp"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            path: "$temp",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            field: 1,
            data: {
                "$concatArrays": [
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$data", []]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull: ["$temp.data", []]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: The problem with this query is that I have the data from "someId1" twice. What I need is from the 3 documents to have 2: one with the data from 1 and 2 and the second with data from 3.

Comment: To get that result I think you should have a different structure. At least i can't think of a solution to only get 2 documents at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Query does those

- lookup(self-lookup) => join if field=associatedField or assosiatedFiled=field,and dont join if same _id to avoide self-joins
- from all the joined, combined their data,and combine them with parent data
- because those data appear 2 times, for doc1 joined doc2, and doc2 joined doc1, i kept only the doc that had the associatedField (the other doc was removed) OR didn't join with any (for example the doc with "someid3" is kept because didnt join with any)

Try it on your data, maybe it is what you wanted to do, but i dont know seems weird things to me, its better i think to change your schema.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251c996f7e3c64c6511e17b)

Data in

```js
[{
    "_id" :1,
    "field": "someId1",
    "data": [{"foo":"bar"}]
},
{
    "_id" :2,
    "field": "someId2",
    "associatedField": "someId1" ,
    "data": [{"foo":"bar1"},{"foo":"bar2"}]
},
{
    "_id" :3,
    "field": "someId3",
    "data":[{"foo":"bar3"}]
}]
```

**Query** (Ruben Vega first part, helped me on writing it)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "1",
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$match": 
         {"$expr": 
           {"$and": 
             [{"$ne": ["$$id_p", "$_id"]},
               {"$or": 
                 [{"$eq": ["$$field_p", "$field"]},
                   {"$eq": ["$$field_p", "$associatedField"]}]}]}}}],
    "as": "temp",
    "let": 
     {"id_p": "$_id",
      "field_p": "$field",
      "associatedField_p": "$associatedField"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"temp.data": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$temp.data",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": 
         {"$let": 
           {"vars": {"a": "$$value", "d": "$$this"},
            "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$a", "$$d"]}}}}}}},
 {"$set": {"data": {"$concatArrays": ["$data", "$temp.data"]}}},
 {"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$or": 
       [{"$eq": ["$temp", []]},
         {"$and": 
           [{"$ne": ["$associatedField", null]},
             {"$ne": [{"$type": "$associatedField"}, "missing"]}]}]}}},
 {"$unset": ["temp"]}])
```

Results (the 2 documents like the results you wanted)

```js
{
  "_id": 2,
  "field": "someId2",
  "associatedField": "someId1",
  "data": [
    {
      "foo": "bar1"
    },
    {
      "foo": "bar2"
    },
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": 3,
  "field": "someId3",
  "data": [
    {
      "foo": "bar3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (simplier?) approach can be to switch your 'field' and 'associatedField' if you have this last one set, then unwind/group by 'field' only.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "field": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$associatedField",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          "then": "$field",
          "else": "$associatedField"
        }
      },
      "associatedField": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$associatedField",
              undefined
            ]
          },
          "then": "$associatedField",
          "else": "$field"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$field",
      associatedField: {
        "$addToSet": "$associatedField"
      },
      data: {
        "$addToSet": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test the solution here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tk5W-avASjU)